# Xampp Appache Web Server is not running

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed Xampp on ubuntu 22.04 from here https://www.apachefriends.org/.

I followed this [installation guideline](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-xampp-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-linux/). But I can't run Apache Web Server but apache said it's actively running when I checked the status.

[image: Apache runner]

I tried to change the port but it still doesn't run. There is no error in the log. I have no idea what to do as I'm still new with Server and database stuff.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: run this in a new terminal window and try to start apache again, do you get any errors?

`tail -2 /opt/lampp/logs/error_log`

Comment: _"but it still doesn't run"_ - so how _exactly_ did you determine that it wasn't running then? Especially when _"apache said it's actively running when I checked the status."_

Comment: @CBroe Apache Web server always stopped even when I start it over and over again. `Site can't be reached` when opening it in localhost with the configured port